# Display Debug.drawLine() with ArCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to display a Line between two objects that I instantiate with ARCore. I don't have any problem in virtual environnement (without ARCORE) but when I want to adapt it for augmented reality, my markers display but not my Line. I'm struggling to debug it too as I don't have any log with the phone...

my code :

```
  // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
        TrackableHit hit;
        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinBounds | TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon;

        if (Session.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
        {
            if (instantiationState == true) //instantiate greencube on click
            {
                Destroy(landmarkEven);
                andyObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("CubeA", typeof(GameObject)), (hit.Pose.position + new Vector3(0, 1, 0)), hit.Pose.rotation) as GameObject;
                landmarkEven = andyObject;
                instantiationState = false;

            }
            else //instantiate redcube on click
            {
                Destroy(landmarkOdd);
                andyObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("CubeB", typeof(GameObject)), (hit.Pose.position + new Vector3(0, 1, 0)), hit.Pose.rotation) as GameObject;
                landmarkOdd = andyObject;
                instantiationState = true;
            }

            // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
            // world evolves.
            var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

            // Andy should look at the camera but still be flush with the plane.
            andyObject.transform.LookAt(FirstPersonCamera.transform);
            andyObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,
                andyObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, andyObject.transform.rotation.z);

            // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
            andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
        }
        if (landmarkEven != null && landmarkOdd != null)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(landmarkEven.transform.position, landmarkOdd.transform.position, Color.green);
        }
```

The main purpose of this is to instantiate a third object base on the direction of that line. If anyone see something strange with my code, or have any idea to realise it in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is on the phone, then that's because [Debug.DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) is for debugging in the Unity Editor playmode only.